# Need for separate interface and impl for DAO

Tags: java, spring, mocking, dao

We have a typical n-tier java application, and I noticed that our data access layers has DAO's that are of the type FooDAO and FooDAOImpl. I was looking to justify the need for the two and here is my analysis.

1. If you had multiple implementation for the same interface, the abstraction is helpful. But given that we have already made the choice of the framework to be used for the DAOImpl (say iBATIS), is it really required?
2. Help in proxying via Spring. From what I gather, classes that have interfaces can be proxied easily (going the JdkProxy route) rather than classes that have no interfaces (where the cglib route is chosen) and one has the subclass the class to be proxied. Subclassing has its problems where the class to proxied is final or has none default constructors - both of which are highly unlikely at the data access layer. Performance used to be a factor, but from what I hear, it is no longer a cause of concern.
3. Help in mocking. Classes with interfaces are more suited to be mocked by mocking frameworks. I have only heard this, but not seen it in practice - so can't really count on it, but maybe because of the same factors as mentioned in #2 above.

With these points, I don't feel the real need for a separate FooDAO and FooDAOImpl where a simple FooDAO should suffice. Feel free to correct any of the points that I have mentioned.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless i'm mistaken you dont actualy ask a question here? The benefits of using interfaces with injection is already stated in your 'question'...

Comment: Yeah you've stated three good reasons for using an interface and implementation of your DAO. I would have drawn the opposite conclusion to you, namely that there is a need to have an interface!

Comment: @user935439 The question is in each bullet point. While we agree on benefits of interfaces in principle, I wanted to gather opinion on the appetite of reducing class files that I have to write and maintain when benefits of interface in such use case are not fully apparent. Do you know with examples if mocking is easier when you have interfaces involved? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the mockito or easymock framework. It generates mock objects out of interfaces so I guess the interface would be a vital thing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried #3 with Mockito and it was able to mock POJO's without interfaces just fine. With the arguments mentioned against #1 and #2, I am inclined not to go with separate DAO and DAOImpl for now. Feel free to add other points of comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I see a fourth reason:

- Hide implementation details

Depending for instance on the team, the expected lifetime of the software or the amount of change anticipated in the future, it pays to hide as much as possible even if there is only one implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that having a `FooDAO` interface with a single implementation `FooDAOImpl` is generally an anti-pattern. The simpler solution (no separate interfaces for DAOs) is much preferable, unless you have a solid reason otherwise - which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Personally, I would go even further and say that having DAOs at all is not the best choice. I prefer having a single persistence facade class implemented on top of an ORM API such as Hibernate or JPA. Maybe iBATIS is too low-level for that, though.